# Trying to start nginx on VPS, I get "nginx: unrecognized service"

Tags: 12.04, nginx, vps

Following the [How to install rails and nginx with passenger on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu) tutorial from DigitalOcean.com, the seventh step manually starts nginx:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

but fails with the following error:

```
nginx: unrecognized service
```

Answer (score 65):

The `nginx: unrecognized service` error means the startup scripts need to be created.
Fortunately the startup scripts have already been written.

We can fetch them with `wget` and set them up following these steps:

```
# Download nginx startup script
wget -O init-deb.sh https://www.linode.com/docs/assets/660-init-deb.sh

# Move the script to the init.d directory & make executable
sudo mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx

# Add nginx to the system startup
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

Now we can control `nginx` using:

```
sudo service nginx stop 
sudo service nginx start 
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: A perfect answer.

Comment: For my info, why/would we need this if we have an appropriately-configured `/etc/init/nginx.conf`?

Comment: first try this sudo service nginx stop 
sudo service nginx start, if this not working then try above steps.

Comment: The url does not return the script

Comment: The URL changed, it only contains index html file

Comment: The url only return a "nginx welcome page" when wget connects to it. If you connect via Safari or Firefox, the link is correct. Thanks a bunch linode server admins...

Comment: I have installed nginx in /etc directory (/etc/nginx), i have updated script path also:

`PATH=/etc/nginx/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/etc/nginx/sbin/nginx`

but it's not working, do i have to change anything else?

Comment: This is fantastic. I always install Nginx through Passenger when setting up a server for Rails, and I never have these scripts. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

It can also mean that the permissions are wrong on the init script, e.g. you do not have the execute bit set

Answer (score 1):

for me I was running vagrant to setup nginx and forgot to put in the `-y` so the nginx install had not completed. So I just needed to ensure it was fine in my Vagrant init.sh bash file

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Some files required by NGINX may have been deleted or misplaced.

> [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362967/how-can-i-restore-etc-nginx)